# Trouble with Ajax loading while using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am facing a problem while working with jQuery Mobile.

I included all necessary things in the `<head>` of my Index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/standard.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/idangerous.swiper.min.js"></script>
```

I use the Swiper.js on another page. But I know that jQuery Mobile uses Ajax loading that replaces only the `<div data-role="page">` in subsequent pages, so ideally, the head and these js files should remain intact, but it doesn't work. However, Index.html works fine.

Have I misunderstood the concept of Ajax loading that only replaces the content inside `<div data-role="page">`?  Thanks.

Comment: It could be possible that swiper didn't notice the new elements loaded in the DOM and that's why stop working. Could you provide a bit more info on how you use swiper in your web?

Comment: I followed like the official demo like this:

    $(function(){
  var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
    //Your options here:
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true
    //etc..
  });
})

i added this to my <Head> Content in the Index.html

Comment: and where are that script in? In the ajax-loaded content? Or ".swiper-container" is in the loaded content? If the "swiper-container" is inside the element loaded by ajax, swiper would not work because is not the same element. But you could put that code inside a callback function for the jquery mobile load.

Comment: The Script is declared inside <script></script> in the Head Content of my Index.html! I also tried the script to place at the end of my <div data-role="page"> of my page 2...

Comment: The script doesn't work when you put the script at bottom of the loaded content of page 2? That puzzles me. Could you try putting that script on `$(document).ready()`? Or use the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using `mobile.loadPage()` to load your new content and you had a problem because the container or the script are inside that "reloaded" element.

So I would suggest using done to execute that script, something like this:

```
    $.mobile.loadPage("page.html", true).done(function (e, ui, page) {
          var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
                  //Your options here: mode:'horizontal', loop: true //etc.. 
          });
    })
```